# Problem with installation of Rawtherapee

Tags: installation

When I want to install `rawtherapee` from Software Center, it will end with this message

```
install Archives() failed: (Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 262697 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking rawtherapee (from .../rawtherapee_3.0.0~dfsg1-1build1_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/rawtherapee_3.0.0~dfsg1-1build1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/rawtherapee/images/curveType-NURBS.png', which is also in package rawtherapee-data 4.0.9-2
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/rawtherapee_3.0.0~dfsg1-1build1_amd64.deb
Error in function:
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: What is the png file it is trying to overwrite. Have you put that there? If so, have you tried moving it elsewhere? If you did not put it there, have you tried to install rawtherapee before?

Comment: Are you running Ubuntu 12.04 or Quantal?

Answer (score 1):

The file `/usr/share/rawtherapee/images/curveType-NURBS.png` is part of the default `rawtherapee` version in the repositories for ubuntu 12.04 (`rawtherapee_3.0.0~dfsg1-1build1_amd64.deb` in your case); and yet you also seem to have available `rawtherapee-data 4.0.9-2`, which is part of the Ubuntu 12.10 Quantal rawtherapee version as noted [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/quantal/i386/rawtherapee-data/4.0.9-2). Therefore you seem to have available two **incompatible** versions of the program, which will try to replace each other, hence the install errors.

This is a problem that can occur with dpkg, and it is documented [here in detail](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/02/fix-dpkg-error-trying-to-overwrite-x.html).

Firstly, try:

`sudo apt-get -f install`

If this is unsuccessful, the following commands should sort it out:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/rawtherapee_3.0.0~dfsg1-1build1_amd64.deb  
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: Great! I should mark it as solved!